# how do i loop instance name without using "this" keyword?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, instance, movieclip, get-childitem

I created a square and saved it as a movieclip called starContainer, i draged three of them on the stage and gave each one instance names in my flash cs6 named - goldStarContainer1, goldStarContainer2 and goldStarContainer3.

In my library i also have a movieclip of a gold star called goldStar

now i would like to do an if else statment and if its true add the gold star to the right starContainer.

```
public var starScreen:starScreen;
```

FYI // dynamic starScreen MovieClip is added on click

```
for( var i:int = 1; i < 4; i++ )
{
    var levelNumStarNum:String = "L1star"+i;
    var goldStarOnPage:goldStar = new goldStar();

if( shared.data[levelNumStarNum] == undefined )
{
    // add no stars
}
else if( shared.data[levelNumStarNum] == 1 )
{
    // this works
    starScreen.goldStarContainer1.addChild(goldStarOnPage);
}
// but i would like to do something like this...

starScreen.goldStarContainer[i].addChild(goldStarOnPage);
```

I have tryed getChildByName but it keep giving me the error:
Call to a possibly undefined method getChildByName through a reference with static type Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
starScreen.goldStarContainer1.addChild(goldStarOnPage);
```

to this:

```
DisplayObjectContainer(DisplayObjectContainer(starScreen).getChildByName("goldS‌​tarContainer"+i)).addChi‌​ld(goldStarOnPage);
```

and see if it helps

Comment: Call to a possibly undefined method getChildByName through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject. :(

Comment: @LukeDobner weird , so try this: `DisplayObjectContainer(starScreen).getChildByName("goldStarContainer"+i).addChild(goldStarOnPage); `

Comment: sorry it says call to undefined method "addchild" through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject

Comment: @LukeDobner ok , we almost there , try this : `DisplayObjectContainer(DisplayObjectContainer(starScreen).getChildByName("goldStarContainer"+i)).addChi‌​ld(goldStarOnPage);`

Comment: i tried DisplayObjectContainer but still get the undefined method addChild error

Comment: @LukeDobner i have edited my answer one more time. try to use this code now , it seems complicated but it'll work

Comment: @LukeDobner it will be good if you will try to understand what exactly we did here. after that may be you will be able to do this in less  complicated way ! ;)

Comment: String concatenation. Nice.